# Firebase Cloud Functions and Async/Await

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I am using async/await on my Firebase Cloud Functions with Firestore, as they seems to be supported (maybe not officially?).

However I noticed that some of my code is not being executed before the function ends. I always see in my logs that a function finished and a couple of minutes later I see the logs from one part of my function.

I cannot share the exact code of my function but it looks like this (I redacted some parts):

```
exports.newMessages = functions
    .region('europe-west1')
    .firestore
    .document('/REDACTED/{id1}/REDACTED/{id2}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

        // some code removed

        // get the a list of documents
        const someDocs = await someDocuments(context.params.id, context.params.id2);

        someDocs.forEach(async snap => {
            let uid = snap.data().uid;

            if (someCondition) {
                await quickOperation(context.params.id, context.params.id2, uid);
                await sendPushNotification(uid);
            }
        })

        await anotherOperation();
    });
```

The logs inside `quickOperation` and `anotherOperation` appear before the `Function execution took ...` log line. But the logs inside `sendPushNotification` appear after that log line, and about two minutes later.

The code inside `sendPushNotification` performs a series of reads in Firestore and then performs a push notification. This would happen even two minutes after the cloud function run.

- Is the fact that I am using Async/Await the one to blame here?
- Would refactoring and using TypeScript (which also supports Async/Await) help in any way?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Cloud Functions.  You can't use async/await in a foreach callback like that.  Either find a way to iterate that doesn't involve a callback, or collect the promises into an array and use Promise.all to wait for all of the work to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and the quick response!

Comment: just to add: that was it, switching to a simple for loop over `.docs` worked.